# How to convert a string into a list without including a specific character plus without using replace and split methods?

Tags: python

Let's say you have:

```
x = "1,2,13"
```

and you want to achieve:

```
list = ["1","2","13"]
```

Can you do it without the split and replace methods?

What I have tried:

```
list=[]
for number in x:
    if number != ",":
        list.append(number)

print(list) # ['1', '2', '1', '3']
```

but this works only if its a single digit

Comment: What've *you* tried?

Comment: okay I will put it in the question

Comment: Put that in the question

Comment: @AndrewL. why do I have -1?

Comment: @AndrewL. thanks anyway mate :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using that assumes integers using `itertools`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> x = "1,88,22"
>>> ["".join(g) for b,g in itertools.groupby(x,str.isdigit) if b]
['1', '88', '22']
>>>
```

Here is a method that uses traditional looping:

```
>>> digit = ""
>>> digit_list = []
>>> for c in x:
...   if c.isdigit():
...     digit += c
...   elif c == ",":
...     digit_list.append(digit)
...     digit = ""
... else:
...   digit_list.append(digit)
... 
>>> digit_list
['1', '88', '22']
>>>
```

In the real world, you'd probably just use regex...

Comment: So I guess the split method has this (traditional) formula in the background?

Comment: Split method is implemented in C (in Cpython). The logical structure is likely similar, although it is likely optimized in many ways. I've never looked into the source.

Comment: The "else" does not have an if statement. I can tell by the indentation and I tried copying this and pasting it into my editor. From the logic of your code I gather that it means add one last time to the list!? What does it mean to have a standalone "else" statement?

Comment: @BitByBit The `else` clause belongs to the `for` loop. It means that if you've reached the end of the loop without `break`ing out, execute what is in that clause.

Comment: @BitByBit see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('(\d+)', '123,456')
['123', '456']
```

Comment: didn't see your regex solution before posting mine.. :)

Comment: @DaveBensonPhilips wow, there are so many ways solving this problem. Never thought about re. But makes sense.